# Gigya Twitter Login Android

Tags: android, gigya

I'm trying to login via twitter in Android with the Gigya sdk 3.3.0, I have set up the twitter app correctly and everything goes well up to the point when I enter my credentials in the twitter web site and I get redirected to https://socialize.gigya.com/GS/GSLogin.aspx?mt=....

The site just hangs in there and I never get to log in. Has anybody experienced the same situation before?

The Facebook login works just fine, so I don't really think any code would be helpful in this question, I was just wondering if anyone  got any clue on what might be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was going on with my app. All my accounts set up was ok , the problem was that I missed the following method:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (GSAPI.getInstance().handleAndroidPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults))
        return;

    // handle other permissions result here
}
```

That method is only available if your activity extends from BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb which is only available in the latest support library (com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1) I was using v22 and Fragmentactivity extends from a different class, therefore I was unable to override the method.

Answer (score 0):

You should double-check that your Gigya console settings for the APIKey and Twitter social application settings are configured correctly as outlined in Gigya's Documentation for [Setting up Twitter](http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Twitter).  If you are using a CNAME with your configuration or using an API Key not configured for the US datacenter, then your Twitter social application is configured incorrectly.

Additionally, the documentation notes:
Use the following callback URL: `http://socialize.gigya.com/GS/GSLogin.aspx`
Optional: If you are planning on configuring a domain alias (CNAME), please replace 'socialize.gigya.com' with your alias subdomain (CNAME value). i.e., `http://[YOUR-ALIAS-SUB-DOMAIN].yoursite.com/GS/GSLogin.aspx` **Please do not use https.**

The redirected domain appears to be configured with `https` as your redirect is going to `https://socialize.gigya.com/GS/GSLogin.aspx?mt=....`, when it should be `http`.